# Assigning range slider value to individual survey question

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key-value

Heloooo, I'm new to development so sorry if code looks poor. I am building a survey where each question has a range slider with values from 0 to 100, I'm trying to get the number from range slider and assign it to it's question. Each question is an object in the array and I'm trying to add the range result as a key-value pair. It also needs to update if user changes the input. I have tried loads of different ways but nothing works, I think I have a problem with scope as "this" is always Window object and not a question. Please help!

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
    </div>
    <!-- Using only js -->
    
    <ul id="questions">
        <!-- questions will be appended here -->
    </ul>
    
    
</div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    var questionList = document.getElementById("questions");
    var slider = document.getElementById("q-slider");
    var range = document.querySelector(".testRange");
    
    var questions = [
    {
        Q :"You create visions and translate them to strategy and action.",
        id: 1,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You work with initiative and are responsible about results",
        id: 2,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You spot and harness opportunities to create growth and profitability",
        id: 3,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You focus to end-result, spot risks and think impact of your action",
        id: 4,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You negotiate, promote and influence to achieve results.",
        id: 5,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You meet new people, create network to achieve results.",
        id: 6,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You provide clarity, inspiration and focus to team achieve object",
        id: 7,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You coach, teach and develop people for their growth",
        id: 8,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You recognize informal rules and political processes to get results.",
        id: 9,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You work by following rules and procedures to achieve results.",
        id: 10,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You prioritize systematically resource allocation to achieve results.",
        id: 11,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You stay steady and supportive even under stress to produce results. ",
        id: 12,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You analyze complex data and create clear conclusions.",
        id: 13,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You develop continuosly your professional expertise and knowledge.",
        id: 14,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You create new, even imaginative solutions and perspectives to problems ",
        id: 15,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You communicate clearly and effectively.",
        id: 16,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You work well with others towards common goals",
        id: 17,
        result : '' 
    },
    {
        Q :"You know your strengths and weaknesses well.",
        id: 18,
        result : '' 
    },
    ]

    
    var designer = [];
    var planner = [];
    var activator = [];
    
    // Create questions
    for (i=0; i <= questions.length -1; i++) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        
        let question = questions.map(a => a.Q);
        li.innerHTML = question[i];
        
        
        questionList.appendChild(li);
    }
    
    // Add sliders to each question
    $('li').append('<form class="q-slider"></form>');
    $('.q-slider').append('<div class="range question"></div>');
    $('.question').append('<input class="testRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" data-orientation="vertical">');
    
    
    // find ID
    questions.forEach(function (question) {
        let id = questions.map(a => a.id);
    });

    
    // const answerMap = {};
    $(".testRange").on("change", function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var question = $(this)[0].id;
            questions[question] = value;
            // console.log(questions);

        });
        

        console.log(question.id);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can hook an event handler to the `input` event of the slider. From there you can use its index to retrieve the matching question in the array and update the `result` property with the value from the slider. Try this:

```js
let questions = [{ Q: "You create visions and translate them to strategy and action.", result: '' }, { Q: "You work with initiative and are responsible about results", result: '' }, { Q: "You spot and harness opportunities to create growth and profitability", result: '' }]

let $questionList = $('#questions');
let questionHtml = questions.map(q => `<li>${q.Q}<div class="range question"><input class="testRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" data-orientation="vertical"><span class="value">50</span></div></li>`);
$questionList.append(questionHtml);

$questionList.on('input', '.testRange', e => {
  let $slider = $(e.target);
  $slider.next('span').text($slider.val());
  questions[$slider.index('.testRange')].result = $slider.val();  
}); 

$('#debug').on('click', () => console.log(questions));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
<ul id="questions"></ul>
<button id="debug">Get results</button>
```